# How to fetch values from td element using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My html code:

```
<tbody>


<tr style="display:none;">

<tr>

<td class="intervention">

<td class="notes-count">

<span class="ico ico--paper"></span>

2

</td>
```

Now i would need to get the value "2" using `selenium webdriver`. Please help me. I have used `xpath "//div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/" and getattribute("value ")` but which returns null value

Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks in Advance

Comment: My html code:

<tbody>


<tr style="display:none;">

<tr>

<td class="intervention">

<td class="notes-count">

<span class="ico ico--paper"></span>

2

</td>

Comment: some of the code is missing. post the code properly.

Comment: Thanks Uma for the comment. This is my first post and i got confused on where to post the code

Answer (score -1):

Well use **getText** method of WebElement instead of using **getAttribute** method

[Here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html) is like for javadoc API for Selenium WebDriver